# Download file in ionic application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app with ionicframework. I want that the user can downolad pdf files which are in the app. In which folder i must place the files, in template folder? How can the user download the files, i must use < a ui-sref="file.pdf" >< /a >?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PDF files are in the application, you could save them in temporary filesystem and after open with default app (move them).

To get access to the device’s files and directories, you need work with plugin $cordovaFile [(http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)). Here you will find the file system layout.

To open a file on your device with its default application use $cordovaFileOpener2 (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/)

Comment: Yes, i can use $cordovaFile.copyFile to move file from folder app to user chosen folder. Is there a 'Save file dialog' in ionicframework?

Comment: No, these plugins do not provide any UI. You must create yor own file browser to select files or/and directories. But it's not hard, here is a example (https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/ionic-file-browser-app). There are other examples including youtube

Comment: I hope that I have helped in some way. If yes, please check that this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying don't move file.
I used InAppBrowser plugin (in ionic 2 project) and i have a 'a.pdf' file in 'www' folder. i use this code:

In .js file:

```
> openURL(url) {
>     InAppBrowser.open(url,'_system','location=yes');   }
```

In .html file:

```
<button (click)="openURL('a.pdf')">Open pdf
    </button>
```

When i press on button the device ask me to select a program to open file, then i select adobe reader pdf. But adobe reader pdf tells me 'impossible to load file ...'. 
What is the right path (url) to call openURL(url)?
Thank you.